# Implementing loop bounds check via overflow interrupt

Tags: arrays, assembly, runtime, interrupt, bounds-check-elimination

I had this idea today that one could implement a bounds checked loop over an array by constructing an iteration counter that will overflow on the last increment and stop the execution based on the generated overflow interrupt.

So assume you have an array e.g. `int[32]` and you want to iterate that. What you could do now to avoid the bounds check in every loop run is to register an interrupt handler for the overflow interrupt and assign a register to the value `MAX - 32`. This register is incremented on every loop iteration run and the last iteration run will overflow i.e. triggering the interrupt handler. Suppose the interrupt handler could increment the program counter of the original function, this mechanism could be used to avoid bounds checks.

So code like

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  // do something
}
```

could be implemented like

```
// setup interrupt somehow
SOME_REGISTER = MAX - array.length;
while (true) {
  // do something
  SOME_REGISTER++;
}
```

I don't know if this is doable, but I heard Java is doing something like that to avoid null checks in the runtime generated code. Do you think this would be doable or has this ever been considered/tried out by any language runtime?

Comment: The obvious problem with this is that most systems don't have a way of automatically generating an interrupt on overflow. Java avoids null checks by relying on the fact that address 0 isn't mapped to valid memory and any attempt to access this location in memory (and any higher addresses up to a certain point) will cause a page fault that the Java runtime can catch. This is supported by a wide range of CPUs and is the default behaviour of modern non-embbeded operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Taking an exception is very slow**; an array would have to be *huge* to amortize the extra cost of leaving the loop by faulting, even if you could save an instruction inside the loop.

What you've probably read about is [Array bounds checks on 64-bit hardware using hardware memory-protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565312/array-bounds-checks-on-64-bit-hardware-using-hardware-memory-protection) : **making arrays end at the end of a virtual page, and leaving the next page unmapped**.  The VM catches SIGSEGV and delivers an exception to the guest code if an out of bounds exception ever happens.  **This removes the need for bounds checks for *random* accesses, not in a loop.**

**This technique only causes an invalid page fault (segfault) when the guest code actually takes an array bounds exception, *not* for the normal case of exiting a loop over an array.**

---

#### Let's look at how your idea would (not) work:

I think you're talking about MIPS where there's an `addi` instruction that traps on signed overflow.  (Instead of the normal `addiu` that does addition without a conditional trap).

Most other ISAs don't have any efficient way to fault on signed overflow.  x86 has `into` (interrupt of OF is set) but that's a separate instruction from the `add` that might set flags.  You might as well use a conditional branch instead of causing an exception and catching it.  Or just use `dec ecx / jnz` as a loop counter, or count a negative index up towards zero and index from the end of the array.

I think MIPS would require an extra `addi` *inside* the loop for a dedicated counter: MIPS's only addressing mode is `reg+16_bit_constant`.

So if you want to iterate an array you need a pointer increment, or else you'd need an extra `add tmp, base, index` inside the loop.

**A loop needs a jump or branch instruction at the bottom, and it can be a conditional branch for basically no extra cost**.  So in MIPS, you'd calculate the end of the array outside the loop, then write a normal loop like

```
    addu   $t5, $t0, $t4     ; t5 = int *endp = start + byte_length
.loop:                       ; do{
    addiu  $t0, $t0, 4         ;  p++
    lw     $t1, ($t0)          ; *p
    ...
    bne    $t0, $t5, .loop    ; }while(p != endp)
```

There are no wasted instructions inside the loop.  Any array bounds-checking can be done *outside* the loop, by checking that `endp` is no more than one past the end of the array.

(On modern x86, `cmp/jne` works equivalently, decoding to a single compare-and-branch uop.  Many other ISAs have a decrement-and-branch or similar instruction that allow counter loop conditions to only have one instruction of overhead.)

`i < array.length` as a loop condition isn't just an array bounds check.

As I said above, in a simple loop that iterates `arr[i]`, you hoist the bounds-check out of the loop to keep it efficient that way.

Comment: The idea I had was to remove the conditional jump by an unconditional one and by doing some tricks(trigger an overflow), rely on some processor mechanism(interrupt) to exit the loop. Thanks for your great explanation. I suppose this has not been attempted because interrupt handler invocation is pretty slow compared to an equality check and probably also because branch prediction helps a lot there?

Comment: @ChristianBeikov: Right, loop branches predict correctly almost every time.  The usual cost is 1 mispredict on the final iteration (where it falls through instead of being taken).  This mispredict is vastly cheaper than taking an exception; depending on the loop and the following code it can be mostly hidden by out-of-order exec, on modern CPUs with fast recovery.  [Avoid stalling pipeline by calculating conditional early](//stackoverflow.com/a/49933702)  Exceptions have to drain the whole back-end.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov: A correctly-predicted conditional branch has the same cost as an unconditional branch.  (And both need prediction in the front-end.  The fetch stage needs to know what block to fetch next before the current block is done decoding.  See [Slow jmp-instruction](//stackoverflow.com/q/38811901))